# sudden blue screen while trying to open a file

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I was trying to open an mp4 file when my laptop(compaq) but suddenly there's blue screen. And I've seen something like: dumping physical memory. Then there was a black screen. I tried powering it off. Then turn on again.

And I saw these:

[image]
[image]

What's the meaning of this.
Does it have something to do with the mp4 file.

**UPDATE**
Here are the screenshots from nircmd's blue screen viewer:

[image]

[image]

I don't really know what those 0 and x means.

Comment: Oh! even in Windows 7 the screen is blue...

Comment: The 0x prefix means that the number is hexadecimal. That usually means that the number is a number of memory location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely a bug with the mp4 codec that you have installed.
You can use [GSpot](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/gspot.htm) to identify which video codec is used on the video file.

You can use [NirSoft BlueScreenView](http://nirsoft.net/utils/blue%5Fscreen%5Fview.html) to try and analyze the dump.
It will also try and guess at the guilty software.

Please post the screenshot of the Details screen that you get in BlueScreenView when double-clicking on the .dmp file, as well as the displayed lower pane after entering F7.

**EDIT**

The info you have posted shows that there is a problem with the Intel Graphics driver.

Your first action should be to download from the Compaq Support website the most recent video driver release for your computer model. You might also at the same time update the chipset driver.

If this doesn't fix the problem, try to use [Update Intel Graphics Drivers](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/detect.htm?iid=business+download_gmav).

Better ensure before doing this that you have backups for your data, and create a system restore point.

Comment: +1 - Better than my (removed) answer. :)